# Why did this transaction, with many contract self destructs, include such a large (34ETH) transaction fee?

Tags: transactions, gas-price, selfdestruct

The transaction [`0xd0820f45ddc180231076a9b28f73f8d124ab296ad7cc7c87c745e0d44a461595`](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd0820f45ddc180231076a9b28f73f8d124ab296ad7cc7c87c745e0d44a461595/advanced) in block [`#124627591`](https://etherscan.io/block/12462759) paid a ~34ETH transaction fee. **Why?** Does this have to do with the number of contract self destructs?

Furthermore, the entire block paid ~93ETH in transaction fees. A few other transactions ([6ETH](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x96b03e377242e2bff55c8f73cc105a3eae1770f715806cec08766ef730ca1223), [11ETH](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7cafa9afaa8d7ad9e906ed2a0ec441b330fc1dfda29551d303a8f1acf0715c98), [10ETH](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x381eb337c6a3d55e576742f08cfbf7cb58a9f7efb77f4b7cbc77267dbbbb3a09)) also paid, what seems to be, exorbitantly high transaction fees. They all also seem to include multiple contract self destructs.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this have to do with the number of contract self destructs?

No. Those are [Gas Token](https://gastoken.io/) (GST2) contract self-destructs, used to bring down the net gas cost for the overall transaction.

> paid a ~34ETH transaction fee. Why?

The gas price was set to 78,000 Gwei(!).

Why would they submit a transaction with such a high gas price? To increase the likelihood of it being included in a block. Why?

From looking at the transaction flow, I *think* they were trying to avoid having a large leveraged position liquidated by the rapid drop in prices yesterday...